# On click stop in Jplayer

Tags: javascript, html, jplayer

I have a music player fixed in bottom and thumbnail with play button when users click it changes to stop button. Play button works but the stop is not working.
my html code is:

```html
<div class="pos-rlt">
    <div class="bottom"> <span class="badge bg-info m-l-sm m-b-sm">04:08</span> </div>
    <div class="item-overlay opacity r r-2x bg-black">
       <div class="text-info padder m-t-sm text-sm"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i> </div>
       <div class="center text-center m-t-n"> <a href="#"data-toggle="class"><i data-jp-src="songs/18.mp3" class="icon-control-play i-2x text"></i><i class="icon-control-pause i-2x text-active"></i></a> </div>
       <div class="bottom padder m-b-sm"> <a href="#" class="pull-right"> <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> </a> <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> </a> </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/p1.jpg" alt="" class="r r-2x img-full"></a> 
</div>
```

And my java script:

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-jp-src]', function(e){
  e && e.preventDefault();
  var music = {};
  music.title = "18 - One Direction"
  music.mp3 = $(this).attr('data-jp-src');
  music.ogg = "http://all.com/18.ogg"
  myPlaylist.add(music);
  myPlaylist.play(-1);
```

I tried to add

```
$("#icon-control-pause i-2x text-active").click( function() { 
$("#jplayer_N").jPlayer("pause, 0");
});
```

Where `icon-control-pause i-2x text-active` is the class of stop button
and `jplayer_N` is the id of my player.

With Regards

Nai

Comment: `icon-control-pause` is a class, but you've made it id selector with `#`, try to use `$('.icon-control-pause')` instead

Comment: Then it's some other issue. It's hard to tell, because code is not complete. Can you create [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I will edit and put the whole script

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net? it would be much easier to tell where the error is

Comment: I will do it as fast as i can

Comment: It's here: https://jsfiddle.net/4xhbyv4p/1/

Comment: Please have a look at it

Comment: please adjust your fiddle. I can't see any thumbnails or play icons. Include the full path in your html.

Comment: That's because there more files so I will mail you the files

Comment: I think I have got one of your mail address

Comment: Please don't mail me. Adjust the fiddle. Then more people can help you I won't reply to your email. I will delete it